# How to mock HTML Import for testing

Tags: web-component, web-component-tester, sinon-chai, html-imports

I am writing tests for my custom element. I use [Web Component Tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester), so it would be great to use Sinon.js for mocking.

My custom element adds `<link rel="import" href="something.html">` dynamically.

How can I stub content for `something.html`?

Comment: you can stub out elements, as described here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/tests (look for Create stub elements)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to mock HTML Import, not the Custom Element. The imported document does not have to contain any element definition.

Comment: component.js https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/tree/master/src/HTMLImports has a polyfil for HTML import. Perhaps you can re-purpose that?